# MarginalDistribution with Symbolic range in ProbabilityDistribution

Tags: symbolic, probability-or-statistics, distributions

Given the following joint density:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

for 10 < x < 20, x/2 < y < x.

To find the marginal density for X we do:

```
PDF[MarginalDistribution[ProbabilityDistribution[1/25 ((20 - x)/ x), 
                                                 {x, 10, 20}, {y, x/2, x}], 1], x]
```

But this does nothing because the range of values for `y` is dependent on `x` and non-numeric.

But the marginal density w.r.t `x` is just the value of the following integral:

```
Integrate[1/25 ((20 - x)/x ), {y, x/2, x}]
```

Which correctly gives

```
(20 - x)/50
```

If we now change the same for a different distribution with a numerical range:

```
PDF[MarginalDistribution[ProbabilityDistribution[2/3 (x + 2 y), 
                                                 {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}], 1], x]
```

we get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is correct since:

```
Integrate[2/3 (x + 2 y), {y, 0, 1}]
```

gives:

```
2/3 + (2 x)/3
```

So my question is why doesn't the symbolic range work, if internally *Mathematica* is just doing the same integration I did above.?

Comment: Played with this for a bit, no luck, my guess is it's one of those not fully realized pieces of the probability functionality. Might be worth a ping to WRI support.

Comment: @rasher, that was my conclusion too. Thanks for taking a crack at it.

Comment: Just as a minor note:  `1/25 ((20 - x)/(x y))`  should be 1/25 ((20 - x)/(x)) ... though it does not change the substance of the issue you raise.

Comment: @wolfies. Thanks, I've corrected it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comparing with *mathStatica* output ...

```
       f  = ((20 - x)/(25*x)); 
domain[f] = {{x, 10, 20}, {y, x/2, x}};
```

Then:

[image]

works fine, so there does seem to be something odd with the Wolfram algorithm here.

Having said so, the best technique to use when dealing with functions that have dependency in the domain of support (as your example has) is to place all the dependency into the joint pdf itself (the *density* part) using `Boole` or `Piecewise`, so that the domain `{{x, 10, 20}, {y, a, b}}` part is a rectangular set. For your example, we could enter say:

```
        g  = ((20-x)/(25x)) * Boole[x/2 < y < x]; 
 domain[g] = {{x, 10, 20}, {y, 0, 20}};
```

The range of values on `y` just has to be large enough to cover the full domain of support ... if you don't want to think, simply enter `y` on the real  line `{y, -Infinity, Infinity}` to cover all cases.

Then:

[image]

where I am again using the `Marginal` function in the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*. The Wolfram version works fine with this setup:

```
 PDF[MarginalDistribution[ProbabilityDistribution[g, {x, 10, 20}, {y, 0, 20}], 1], x]
```

Setting things up this way is a good habit to get into, because it makes it easy to use other *Mathematica* functions such as `Plot3D` to plot the joint pdf:

```
Plot3D[g, {x, 10, 20}, {y, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`Boole` allows evaluation:

```
f[x_, y_] := (20 - x)/(25 x) Boole[x/2 < y < x]
pd = ProbabilityDistribution[
  f[x, y], {x, 10, 20}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
PDF[MarginalDistribution[pd, 1], x]
```

[image]

Comment: And it's free! +1